# Create JUnit unit test methods and cover during code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, code-coverage

I am new into writing test methods using JUnit. Can someone help me or atleast give me sample of how can I write test method for this method which will cover it all during code coverage?

Here is my method, wherein `device` can have single or multiple (comma separated) values, e.g. Apple or Apple,Samsung,Xiaomi

```
public List<String> getDeviceList(String device) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(device)) {
            List <String> deviceList = Stream.of(device.split("[, ]")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return deviceList ;
        }
        return null;
   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Better return `Collections.emptyLis()` instead of `null`

Comment: You'd just instantiate an object from this class and call the `getDeviceList` method… first time with `null` as input, second time with `Apple,Samsung,Xiaomi` as input. Did you try it?